# Securing secret keys in Android

Tags: android, web-services, security

I have a web service that does some payment operation, so it's very critical. Of course it has a secret key that can't be called without.

I'll assume that sooner or later my .apk file will be decompiled and the code will be readable. Now, if I decided to receive that key by calling another service, the url of that service will be stored in my code, but I've just said that it's not secure and can't be hidden!!

What is the best approach in such situation?

Comment: Why put the secret key in the application? Presumably there's a server component to this. Use the secret there and place the public key in your app.

Comment: @Mike W: if I could understand you, isn't it dangerous to place a public key in my app? I need not to allow the possible hacker to call my services and steal my contents.

Comment: I misunderstood the question from your use of terminology. If that's your problem then you'll need to get the user to authenticate somehow. Perhaps force a login once, and provide a unique key to each user at that time. Once the unique key is issued and stored on the device, there'd be no need to login. You might repeat the process periodically, and possibly tie the key to a device-specific ID (the IMEI number, perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a security expert, but I guess [oAuth](http://oauth.net/) would be a good choice. Sites like Google use it for authenticating, and it's secure. The user needs to sign in using his credentials, and the application receives an oAuth token and secret to make API calls.

In that case, decompiling the application won't help the hacker, since he'll still need the credentials of users.

It requires changes on both the server and the client side, but I don't think that's a problem, since security is more important in this case.

Comment: thanks, you're right. but what if there's no login in my application?

Comment: In that case, it's not secure. Everyone could just use [http://www.wireshark.org/download.html](Wireshark) to trace the URL calls and make the exact same calls. You could make it a little bit harder by using an algorithm to add a value to the request which is only valid for a few seconds, but that's far from being 'secure'.